# getting seg fault on malloc'ing for a string array. please help

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
------------------  
#include<stdlib.h>  
--------------------  
#include<string.h      
--------------------  

enum { buf = BUFSIZ };

char line[buf], **tab = NULL;

 int cur_buf, count_lineMax = -1, count_line = -1,
    i, j, k, l;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

        FILE *file1;
        file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        cur_buf = buf;

        /*printf("%d\n", cur_buf);*/


                while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) {

                        i = strlen(line);

                        for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
                                if(line[j] == '\n') {
                                        count_lineMax++;
                                }
                                /*printf("%c", line[j]);*/
                        }

                }
                /*printf("%d\n", count_lineMax);*/

                rewind(file1);

                tab = malloc(count_lineMax);
                memset(tab, 0, count_lineMax);


                for(k=0;k<count_lineMax;k++) {
                        tab[k] = malloc(cur_buf+1);
                        memset(tab[k], 0, cur_buf+1);
                }

                        while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) {
                                i = strlen(line);

                                for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
                                        if(line[j] == '\n') {
                                                count_line++;
                                        }
                                }
                        tab[count_line] = line;
                        printf("%s", tab[count_line]);
                        }
        return 0;
        for(l=0;l<count_lineMax;l++) {
                free(tab[l]);
        }

        free(tab);
        fclose(file1);
}
## Heading ##
```

Comment: tab[count_line] = line; I assume this is correct based on malloc'd array

Comment: I meant - please edit the question, add some more details ;-P

Comment: `enum { buf = BUFSIZ };` looks like nonsense

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated enough memory for your lines.

```
char **tab;

tab = malloc(count_lineMax);
memset(tab, 0, count_lineMax);
```

`count_lineMax` is the number of lines that are in the file and you are trying to allocate memory to store that many lines.  You only allocate `count_lineMax` *bytes* of memory but that's not enough for `count_lineMax` *pointers*.  Those lines should read:

```
tab = malloc(count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
memset(tab, 0, count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab));
```

After that, you attempt to allocate more memory to store `count_lineMax` pointers and you overflow your memory corrupting the heap.

Furthermore, the second time you read in your file, you are writing to your `file` buffer and storing that buffer in your `tab` array.  You're leaking the memory you had previously allocated and you attempt to `free()` this buffer which is wrong.  So any of those problems are causing the segmentation fault.

```
while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) { /* read into `line` */
    /* ... */
    tab[count_line] = line; /* DEATH! */
}
/* ... */
for(l = 0; l < count_lineMax; l++) {
    free(tab[l]); /* DOUBLE DEATH! *?
}
```

You need to either read your lines directly into your allocated buffers correctly:

```
count_line = 0;
while(fgets(&tab[count_line], cur_buf, file1) != NULL) { /* read into `line` */
    /* ... */
    count_line++;
}
```

Or *copy* the contents of the `line` buffer into your allocated ones.  That way you're not leaking your memory and freeing the wrong ones.

```
count_line = 0;
while(fgets(line, cur_buf, file1) != NULL) { /* read into `line` */
    /* ... */
    strcpy(tab[count_line], line);
    count_line++;
}
```

There are other issues with the code but I won't go over them as these are higher priority.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! It doesn't seg fault anymore. But I still I am trying to understand why count_lineMax * sizeof tab should be allocated. Is that not done by default? Forgive this noob if it's trivial. Yet, I hope to get this thing straightened out.

Comment: @gyan: Sorry, I've mistyped that, should have been `count_lineMax * sizeof(*tab)`.  Suppose `count_lineMax` is `1`.  The way you have it, you are allocating `1` byte of memory.  However the `tab` variable should have enough memory to point to a pointer.  It would likely be `4` bytes in size per address.  However you've only allocated `1` byte but attempt to store a `4` byte pointer there causing an overflow.  I've explained further in my edit.

Comment: "You need to either read your lines directly into your allocated buffers"

Comment: "You need to either read your lines directly into your allocated buffers" ? you mean read in to tab? Also when I try to free(), am I trying to free "line" buffer? I assumed storing buffer contents into allocated memory is as good as copying! I'd wait for more from you Jeff. thanks so much!

Comment: Went more into detail on those in my update.

Comment: now I am stuck at the second dimension! is it again the pointer muck up?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you never check that count_line is in range so tab[count_line] could be invalid when you assign to it.

Comment: you mean I overrun the count_lineMax? How do I go about that? Thanks a lot ! Now I have one more thing to understand!